# Xamarin Android - Turn off Mono Logs

Tags: android, logging, mono, console, xamarin

This might be a nit-picky thing, but in Xamarin when running an Android app, it dumps tons of lines in the console that start with `[Mono]`

Is there any way to disable these logs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This can be done by changing the state of Monos execution environment on the device; which is just a set of environment variables that alters Monos behaviour (be it garbage collection, logging etc). In this case, to alter the logging behavior we need to modify the values stored in the environment variables `MONO_LOG_LEVEL` and `MONO_LOG_MASK`.

Xamarin.Android offers 2 mechanisms developers can use to change the execution environment:

- **1.** Using `adb shell setprop debug.mono.env`. This can be done as a post build action.
- **2.** Using an environment build file to change the execution environment state per project.

I prefer to use method 2 as it's easier to edit a text file than changing build actions. Do this using the steps outlined below.

### Adding An Environment File

Add a plain text file called `environment.txt` to the root path of your Xamarin.Android project.
[image]

Right click on `environment.txt` and set its build action to `AndroidEnvironment`.

The environment file is series of *key=value* pairs seperated by newlines. For logging, we can set the following variables:

**MONO_LOG_LEVEL**

- **debug**
- **info**
- **message**
- **warning**
- **critical**
- **error**

**MONO_LOG_MASK**

- **asm**
- **dll**
- **cfg**
- **all**
- **type**
- **gc**

For example, we can ignore most messages by filtering `MONO_LOG_LEVEL` by error:

**environment.txt**

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=error
```

Background reading:

- [Android Environment](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/environment/)
- [Mono - Logging Runtime Events](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/logging-runtime-events/)

Comment: Thanks so much, Matt! Answers my question and then some :)

Comment: Pleasure :) FYI, this file is also used to control which garbage collection algorithm is used by Mono. You can use `MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=##` to experiment with the different algorithms if your app is thrashing the GC and becoming non-responsive as a result.

Comment: I did all this but am not sure if it's changing anything. How do I know that these parameters are being compiled in properly?

Comment: @PsychoDad, for the log level filtering, most of the `mono-stdout` logging will vanish. For the GC implementation, the garbage collection message will show something like `GC_OLD`, `GC_NEW` or `GC_TARJAN` each type a collection is triggered.

Comment: @matthewrobbinsdev I must be doing something wrong. I've created the file and set the build action to AndroidEnvironment but I don't think it's picking it up. I can out gibberish in the file and I get no build errors. I guess I can email Xamarin support.

Comment: All these years of suffering, finally had the clever idea of googling about it :)) Thx so much Matt!

Comment: @jjxtra Did you ever get this to work? Have the same issue right now

Comment: No, stopped using Xamarin years ago

Comment: @matthewrdev Did this, but appears to have no effect - any thoughts what could be wrong? Do I perhaps need to restart ADB server, VS or the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

What I do is below. It's still imperfect as the window holds 10k logs, including the hidden ones, so mine eventually disappear. Additionally, I can't seem to copy from the window.

1) Use a tag of "AAA" for all my logs.
2) View the output in Tools>Android>Device Log
3) Sort alphabetically by Tag.
4) I find that the outputs beneath mine are still distracting. I can click the "filter" for the Tag and uncheck everything but mine. Annoyingly, I have to repeat this step periodically as new tags are not filtered by default.

[image]

Comment: How do you add the "Tag"?